# Consequence of the convergence of the series \sum_{n}\sin(nt)

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

It is known that if  $\sum_{n}a_{n}<\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=0$.
How to explain the situation of the series $\sum_{n}\sin(nt)$, for a fixed $0<t<2\pi$, since this series converges but the sequence of terms $\sin(nt)$ does not converges?

Comment: Thx! i realized right after posting the question...

Answer (score 1):

The series does not converge - it does not settle down to a single number.  On the other hand, it doesn't increase unboundedly either, but it still doesn't converge.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ to converge, the sequence of partial sums $s_{N}=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}$ must converge.  The sum may not be infinite, but it still "diverges" if the sequence of partial sums does not converge.

In your case, the $a_{n}$ do not go to zero, so the sequence of partial sums does not converge, so the series diverges (even though the sum may not be infinite).